# If $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $\tau=\inf\left\{t>0:f(t)>\varepsilon\right\}$, then $f(\tau\wedge t)\le\varepsilon$ for all $t\ge0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, stopping-times

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be continuous, $\varepsilon>0$ and $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t>0:f(t)>\varepsilon\right\}.$$ Are we able to show that $f(\tau\wedge t)\le\varepsilon$ for all $t\ge0$ (where $x\wedge y:=\min(x,y)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$)?

I'm struggling, since $\left\{t>0:f(t)>\varepsilon\right\}=(0,\infty)\cap f^{-1}\left(\left(\varepsilon,\infty\right)\right)$ is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to show if $\tau > 0$. If $\tau = 0$, it's possible to have $f(0) > \varepsilon$, and so $f(0 \land t) = f(0) > \varepsilon$.

If $\tau > 0$, then for $0 \le x < \tau$, we have $f(x) \le \varepsilon$, otherwise $\tau$ would not be a lower bound for $\{ t > 0 : f(t) > \varepsilon\}$. In particular, if we take $x_n \to \tau$, with $x_n < \tau$ (e.g. $x_n = \tau(1 - 1/n)$), then by continuity, we must have $f(x_n) \to f(\tau)$, but given $f(x_n)$ lies in the closed set $[0, \varepsilon]$, so does $f(\tau)$. That is, $f(\tau) \le \varepsilon$.

(We could go further and actually prove $f(\tau) = \varepsilon$, but this is not necessary!)

So, $\tau \land t \le \tau$ for all $t$, so either $\tau \land t = \tau$ or $0 \le \tau \land t < \tau$. In either case, we have proven $f(\tau \land t) \le \varepsilon$.

Comment: How do you conclude $f(0)>\varepsilon$ in the case $\tau=0$? Couldn't it be the case that $f(0)=\varepsilon$? Moreover, you didn't treat the case $\tau=\infty$ (in which $f(t)\le\varepsilon$ for all $t>0$, but what can we say about $f(0)$?). Oh, and could you add how we can show $f(\tau)=\varepsilon$?

Comment: If $\tau>0$, I agree that $f(t)\le\varepsilon$ for all $t\in(0,\tau)$, but how do you argue that it is true for $t=0$? (I think you didn't need that for your argument. You just need to replace your $x_n$ by $\tau(1-1/(n+1))$, for example.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d I deleted my previous comment, because it had a couple of errors. We always have $f(\tau) \ge \varepsilon$, even when $\tau = 0$. Why? Because $\tau + \frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for the set, so we can choose $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) > \varepsilon$ and $\tau \le x_n < \tau + \frac{1}{n}$, i.e. $x_n \to \tau$. So, by continuity, $f(\tau) \ge \varepsilon$. But no, we cannot conclude that $f(\tau) \le \varepsilon$ when $\tau = 0$, since $f(0)$ may simply be larger than $\varepsilon$. For example, what if $f$ is constantly $\varepsilon + 1$?

Comment: Okay, but if we replace $\tau$ by $\tau:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:f(t)>\varepsilon\right\}$ and assume $f(0)=0$, then we can conclude that either $\tau=\infty$ (which is the case precisely when $f(t)\le\varepsilon$ for all $t\ge0$) or $\tau\in(0,\infty)$ and $f(\tau)=\varepsilon$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes. If $f(0) = 0$, then since $f(\tau) \ge \varepsilon > 0$, it follows that $\tau \neq 0$, which means $f(\tau) = \varepsilon$.